# (JQuery) Selecting html element

Tags: jquery

What I want to do is select in jquery the option element which value is `'myvalue'` which is inside a DIV element which id is `mydiv`.

This is what I tried:

```
$("#myid option[value=myvalue]")
```

But this doesnt work in my code.

Comment: Can you post your html structure please? are you looking for the option? or the select that option belongs to?

Comment: If the id is `"mydiv"`, why are you using `"myid"` in the selector?

Answer (score 4):

I would say

```
$('#mydiv option[value="myvalue"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

You said that the div id was 'mydiv' so

```
$("#mydiv option[value=myvalue]")
```

Answer (score 1):

The id in your selector is wrong try this. You have used `myid` instead of `mydiv` which is the `id` of the `div` element you mentioned in your question.

```
$("#mydiv option[value=myvalue]")
```